# How to get count & word string that repeats multiple times in a column

Tags: r

Hello I'm working on NPS & CSAT analysis. I have a column full of customer comments and trying to identify their issues and root cause of the problem.

```
comments <- c("My order took too much time to deliver.",
 "Logistics is the main problem.",
 "Late time delivery.",
 "Why do you need additional time to deliver my product.",
"You need to streamline your process towards quick delivery")
```

And the output should be:
Column B (Word) | Column C (Count)
Time | 3
Delivery | 3
Problem | 1

Is there a code snippet to achieve this ? Any recommendations ?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're looking for specifically. A reproducible example with desired output would help clarify. I'd recommend the `tidytext` package and its `unnest_tokens` function for this. https://www.tidytextmining.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tidytext` package - specifically the `unnest_tokens` function:

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
comments <- c("My order took too much time to deliver.",
              "Logistics is the main problem.",
              "Late time delivery.",
              "Why do you need additional time to deliver my product.",
              "You need to streamline your process towards quick delivery")
comment.df <- tibble(comment=comments)

tidy_comments <- unnest_tokens(comment.df, word, comment)

tidy_comments <- tidy_comments %>% count(word, sort=TRUE)
```